# e.printStackTrace() заменяет throw?

Tags: java

Часто встречаю подобный код:

```
Scanner in = null;

try {
  in = new Scanner(new File(FILE_NAME));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

if (in.hasNext()) {
```

В случае исключения вызовется `e.printStackTrace();`, что выведет ошибку в `stderr`, но ведь дальнейшее выполнение метода продолжится с некорректным состоянием?

Comment: https://ideone.com/wJdvdV

Comment: начинающие ява-программисты очень не любят `throws` и большие блоки `try`, поэтому так. Еще в таких вопросах обычно следом за `try-catch` идет проверка на `null`, а инициализация переменной null-ом. появляется после того, как компилятор выдаст ошибку "переменная возможно не инициализирована".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Представленный в вопросе код плох в любом случае:

1. Если исходное исключение важно (например, этот метод в библиотеке и вызывается извне), то, вероятно, разработчики, использующие эту библиотеку, "отвесят низкий поклон" её создателям за невозможность обработать исключение так как им надо и за  довольствование stacktrace-ом в stderr
2. Если исключение не важно (важен только результат), то тут всё равно вместо результата будет `NullPointerException`, который ещё и непонятно на каком уровне будет обработан. Даже если вызывающая сторона обладает знанием (из документации или магическим образом) того что нужно отлавливать `NullPointerException` и показывать при этом пользователю сообщение "Файл не найден", то при наличии в методе других потенциальных мест возникновения `NullPointerException`, эта логика рискует оказаться сломанной

---

К каким выводам можно прийти:

1. Если метод используется в библиотеке, то имеет смысл пробрасывать исходное исключение (возможно, в какой-то обёртке). Даже если с точки зрения бизнес-логики важен только результат, то для отладки исключение вполне может понадобиться
2. Если метод является внутренним для программы, то тут уже "на вкус и цвет". Где-то имеет смысл "проглотить" исключение и сделать в `catch`, например, `return null` (или дальнейшую логику с `in` обернуть в `if (in != null)`, если возникшее исключение - ещё не повод прекращать работу метода), где-то - пробросить вверх и обработать, например, глобально

Answer (score 1):

Все правильно, если в блоке catch (Exception e) происходит обработка исключительной ситуации. Метод printStackTrace() выводит трассировку ошибки на экран. В данном блоке Вам необходимо либо аварийно завершить программу

```
System.exit(-1)
```

Или же предпринять действия, чтобы в дальнейшем программа корректно завершила работу.

Answer (score -1):

Некорректного состояния не будет, так как ссылка будет указывать на null, следовательно `if (in.hasNext())` выбросит вам исключение в рантайм `NullPointerException`

Comment: И каковы же причины считать это корректным состоянием?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь вызвать метод, которого нет, думаю это корректное состояние.