# Ошибка чтения/записи при работе с файлом(Java EE)

Tags: java, файлы, java-ee

Добрый день, возникла очень не понятная ошибка... Дело в том, что у меня некоторые данные хранятся в файле, при развертывании TomCat происходит удачное считывание с файлов. Но также у меня есть админка - там у пользователя есть возможно изменить данные в файле, после перезаписывании данных вылетает исключение(NullPointerException) видите ли такого файла не существует, хотя он находится там я проверял... Вообще не понятная ситуацию, вот методы для записи и чтение данных из файла:

#### Считывание

```
public synchronized String readFile(String filePath){
    StringBuffer txt = new StringBuffer();
    List<String> lines = null;
    try {
        lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath.toString()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error reading from: " + filePath);
    } catch (NullPointerException e){
        log.error("Incorrect path : " + filePath);
    }
    for(String line: lines){
        txt.append(line);
    }
    return txt.toString();
}
```

#### Запись

```
public synchronized void writeFile(String filePath, String data){
    try {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(filePath, false);
        out.write(data);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Error writing to file: " + filePath);
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь подскажет какая причина этого, потому что сам уже 2-ой день бьюсь с этим. Вот собственно ошибки, которые мне выдаются:

```
Type Exception Report
Message An exception occurred processing JSP page [/admin_room.jsp] at line [39]
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/admin_room.jsp] at line [39] 

36:                 <form action="/CommonData" name="change_common_titels" 
method="POST" class="wrapper_admin row">
37:                     <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5">
38:                         <label class="label_admin">Р—Р°РіРѕР»РѕРІРѕРє 
РЅР°Р·РІР°РЅРёСЏ СЃРёСЃС‚РµРјС‹ С‚РµСЃС‚РёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРёСЏ:</label>
39:                         <input name="name_test" type="text" 
class="input_admin" value="<%=FactoryModels.getCommonData(path + 
"title_test.txt")%>">
40:                     </div>
41:                     <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5">
42:                         <label class="label_admin">Р—Р°РіРѕР»РѕРІРѕРє 
СЂРµР·СѓР»СЊС‚Р°С‚Р° С‚РµСЃС‚РёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРёСЏ:</label>

Stacktrace:

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:481)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
ru.tidstu.testingsystem.servlets.DispatcherServlet.forward(DispatcherServlet.java:22)
ru.tidstu.testingsystem.servlets.admin_room.CommonDataServlet.doPost(CommonDataServlet.java:38)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Root Cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
ru.tidstu.testingsystem.models.IOFile.readFile(IOFile.java:33)
ru.tidstu.testingsystem.models.FactoryModels.getCommonData(FactoryModels.java:107)
org.apache.jsp.admin_005froom_jsp._jspService(admin_005froom_jsp.java:152)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
ru.tidstu.testingsystem.servlets.DispatcherServlet.forward(DispatcherServlet.java:22)
ru.tidstu.testingsystem.servlets.admin_room.CommonDataServlet.doPost(CommonDataServlet.java:38)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Добавь полный стэк исключения с сообщением ошибки.

Comment: + раз уж это NPE то ещё и строку укажите где вылетает.

Comment: Добавил информацию об ошибке

Comment: Укажите где в readeFile 33 строка.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/740062/178988

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас имеется следующий код, где вы ловите исключения в случае, если что-то пошло не так при чтении файла:

```
try {
    lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath.toString()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Error reading from: " + filePath);
} catch (NullPointerException e){
    log.error("Incorrect path : " + filePath);
}
```

Однако после обработки этих исключений переменная `lines` остаётся со значением `null` - и при последующей попытке обхода мы получаем `NullPointerException`:

```
for(String line: lines){
    txt.append(line);
}
```

Скорее всего, данный обход списка тоже нужно перенести внутрь блока `try-catch`.

P.S.: И при обработке `IOException` желательно сохранить исходное сообщение - по нему будет проще понять, что пошло не так:

```
catch (IOException e) {
    log.error(String.format("Error reading from file '%s': %s", filePath, e.getMessage()));
}
```

P.P.S.: Кстати, можно упростить метод чтения:

```
public synchronized String readFile(String filePath){
    try {
        return Files
            .lines(Paths.get(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .collect(Collectors.joining());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Хмм... В принципе работает, только есть одна проблема... Теперь исключение не вылетает, но после первой перезаписи данных поля становятся пустыми, а потом уже работает как надо.

Comment: И после перезагрузки TomCat, возвращаются старые значения в файлах, мб я не тот путь даю к файлам или что тогда?

Comment: @БалунВладимир проверьте все пути, которые указаны. Если при записи нет ошибок и путь верный - прочитать старые данные вряд ли получится. И да, вместо `FileWriter` можно использовать `Files.write()`.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы проще сделал:

```
public synchronized String readFile(String filePath){
    StringBuffer txt = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        List<String> lines = null;
        lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath.toString()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for(String line: lines){
            txt.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        log.error("Error reading from file: " + filePath);
    }
    return txt.toString();
}
```

т. е. все в один блок `try`, кроме `txt`. В случае ошибки, метод вернет пустую строку и отпишет об этом в лог.